# PHP - Loop custom post type categories within jQuery Tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have a custom post type called 'Products'

Within products there is a custom field called 'Sub Category' (selsubcat) which contains 14 different categories.

These categories are; CAM / REC / ACC / SWH / NET / MON / HDMI / ENC / SIGNS / PIR / WIFI / POLE / SOUND.

What I am trying to do display all the products within a different tab, where the tabs are the sub categories, and each tab will display the products for that category. At the moment I've defined the `meta_value` as 'CAM' and this is displaying all the products with the category 'CAM' within the `#tabs-1` div - which is correct.

I now need to somehow loop each category and display the products in the other 13 tabs.

So `#tabs-1` will show all the products for the category 'CAM', `#tabs-2` will show all the products for the category 'REC' and so on...

Here is what I have at the moment:-

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <?php
        if( have_rows('sub_category', 'option') ): $cat_increment = 1;
            while ( have_rows('sub_category', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <!-- Tab Sub Categories -->
                <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $cat_increment; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('category_name'); ?></a></li>
            <?php $cat_increment++; endwhile;
        else : endif;
        ?>
    </ul>

    <?php 

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'products',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_key'      => 'selsubcat',
        'meta_value'    => 'CAM'
    ));

    if( $posts ): ?>


    <div id="tabs-1">   

        <table id="table-products" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">id</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Total Cost</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">id</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Total Cost</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>                        

                <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

                    setup_postdata( $post );

                    ?>

                    <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td class="hidden"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                              <td><span class="product-image" style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);"></span></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('code'); ?></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('description'); ?></td>
                              <td><?php the_field('cost_price'); ?></td>
                              <td><input type="text" /></td>
                              <td><input type="text" /></td>
                              <td><input type="button" class="add-row" name="add-row" value="Add"></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>

                <?php $product_increment++; endforeach; ?>

            </table>    

        </div>


        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I'm stuck at this point so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First store all categories id in an array, than in `foreach` loop get each categories name and posts and save them in an other array (category name as key and posts as value), now you have an array that stored all posts and categories in it!

```
$categories_id = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$posts = array();
foreach ($categories_id as $id) {
    $term = get_term($id,'product_category');
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $id
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post(); 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumbnail' );
        $posts[$term_name][] = array(
                                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                                    'link'  => get_the_permalink(),
                                    'image' => $image[0]
                                );
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

To print array into tabs :

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <?php
            $count = 0;
            $class = "active";
            foreach ($posts as $key => $value) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="#tab<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></a></li>
        <?php
                if($count == 0)
                    $class = "";
                $count++;
            endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <?php
            $count = 0;
            $class = "active";
            foreach ($posts as $key => $value): ?>
                <div id="tab<?php echo $count; ?>" class="tab <?php echo $class; ?>">
                <?php
                    foreach ($posts[$key] as $post) : 
                        //echo post['title']
                        //echo post['link']
                        //echo post['image']
                    endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        <?php
                if($count == 0)
                    $class = "";
                $count++;
            endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @aidinMC - I'm not able to get this to work still, essentially I just need to loop each category with a different meta value, so 'REC' will be inside <div id="tab-2"></div>, 'ACC' will be inside <div id="tabs-3"></div>, SWH will be inside <div id="tabs-4"></div> and so on.